# Revert all changes in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Is there a way to revert all the changes that I made into document since I opened it?

Of course I could just close it without saving it and reopen it again, but may be there is a faster way?

Comment: I,m also interested in this, I know only Ctr + alt + Z to undo, but this will stop at certain point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not quite the same as reverting all history since the document opened, but: if you're just looking for a faster way than your "closing without saving" method, then **File** → ***Revert*** will expedite that for you.

The default keyboard shortcut for this command is <kbd>F12</kbd>.

Adobe Help docs: [**Revert to the last saved version**](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/photoshop/cs/using/WSfd1234e1c4b69f30ea53e41001031ab64-749da.html#WSfd1234e1c4b69f30ea53e41001031ab64-749ba)

Comment: Despite the other answer about the "History" window is more upvoted, I choose your answer as it perfectly fit my needs. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

You need to open history panel: `Window > history`, and click on the first thumbnail (which is state, when you opened document)